# Using reflection throws error in EF Core 3

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, entity-framework-core

We formerly used reflection to create linq queries, e.g. for the GetById method:

```
private IQueryable<T> GetQueryById(TKey id)
{
    var query = _dbset; //DbSet<T>

    var keyNames = _context.Model
            .FindRuntimeEntityType(typeof(T))
            .FindPrimaryKey()
            .Properties
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();

    if (keyNames.Count() == 1)
    {
        query = query.Where(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(keyNames[0]).GetValue(e, null)
           .Equals(id)); //throws error
    }
        
    return query;
}
```

This does not seem to work any more in EF Core 3:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(__get_Item_0).GetValue(
> obj: c,
> index: null).Equals((object)__id_1))' could not be translated.

Is it possible to rewrite the query so that EF Core does not complain?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the performance of your previous "working" solution? It's not only doing reflection for each item, but also does that after retrieving the whole table in memory. Search SO or EF Core documentation for "client evaluation" and why it has been removed in EFC 3.0. What about how to rewrite the query properly, you have to build expression, for instance like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240968/entity-framework-filter-by-primarykey/42244905#42244905

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510132/4413289
and don't forget to vote Up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create predicate dynamically:

```
private IQueryable<T> GetQueryById(TKey id)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbset; //DbSet<T>

    var keyNames = _context.Model
            .FindRuntimeEntityType(typeof(T))
            .FindPrimaryKey()
            .Properties
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();

    if (keyNames.Count == 1)
    {
        var keyExpression = Expression.Constant(id);
        var entityParam   = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var body          = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(entityParam, keyNames[0]), keyExpression);
        var predicate     = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, entityParam);

        query = query.Where(predicate); 
    }
    else
      // better to throw exception
      throw new Exception($"Cannot find entity key.");
        
    return query;
}
```